# Fetching session value from webmethod gives error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have set the current page's session values in webmethod and i am trying to get those session values and set them to variables in javascript.
In my webmethod, this is the code for setting session value:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("benchmark", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("bm"))
```

It works and ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("bm") gives 2. The following is my script which couldnt fetch the session value and gives the value as 0.

var bm='<%=Session("benchmark").toString %>';

my full javscript is:

```
function ddlpf_SelectedIndexChanged(selectedItemValue)
{
   btn_enable(false);
   var i;
   var userid='<%=Session("userid").toString %>';
   if(ddlpf.selectedIndex > 0)
   {                  
   PageMethods.setpfdetails2(ddlpf.options[ddlpf.selectedIndex].value, userid,onSuc,onErr);
   function onSuc(res){'<%=Session("benchmark")="' + res + '" %>';}
   function onErr(){}
   var bm='<%=Session("benchmark").toString %>';
   var ses='<%=Session("hcur").toString %>';          
   }
alert(bm);
}
```

My full webmethod is:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function setpfdetails2(ByVal pfid As String, ByVal uid As String) As String
    Dim da As New dataaccess, para(2) As Object, ds As New DataSet
    Dim strtemp() As String = {"hcur", "mtm", "amtdis", "ratedis", "rd", "dtformat", "day1type", "benchmark", "covmtm", "dtsep", "impset"}
    Try
        For Each strt As String In strtemp
            If HttpContext.Current.Session.Item(strt) IsNot Nothing Then HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(strt)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    custrefdetails1(pfid, uid)
    Try
        para(0) = "SPADD" : para(1) = uid : para(2) = pfid
        ds = da.retds1("select_portfolio", conn, para)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("hcur", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("hcur"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("mtm", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("mtm"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("amtdis", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("amtdis"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ratedis", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ratedis"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("rd", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("rd"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("dtformat", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("dtformat"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("day1type", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("day1"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("benchmark", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("bm"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("covmtm", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("covmtm"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("covcancel", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("cover"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("mtmamtsel", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("mtmbx"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("dtsep", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("sep"))
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("impset", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("importset"))
        End If
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("datasheettype", ds.Tables(1).Rows(0)(0))
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        ds = Nothing : da = Nothing
    End Try
    Return HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("benchmark")
End Function
```

Comment: shouldn't that be var bm='<%=Session("benchmark").ToString() %>'

Comment: '<%=Session("benchmark")="' + res + '" %>'; gives the error

Comment: The problem here is that `<%=Session("benchmark")%>` is executed only on the first page load, always leaving you with the same value. If you want `benchmark` based on what `setpfdetails2` does, then your WebMethod should *return* that benchmark value and you should then capture it in onSuc. Have a look at this article: http://www.semenoff.dk/en/Code-Corner/ASP.Net.AJAX/WebService-From-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: okay , if i am getting the value from onsuc, then how to set it to the session? @RGraham

Comment: You can set it in the Session whenever you want on the server-side, but the code which reads from the session will only execute on page load. Refresh the page and you'll see those variables updated

Comment: but i am trying to avoid postback. so what to do bro?

Comment: and also i am getting error on setting a variable to session. is the following one correct? '<%=Session("benchmark")="' + res + '" %>';

Comment: I would not recommend storing session values on the client-side. The session data lives on the server for a finite amount of time only; it does so after typically a sliding expiration time has elapsed. You should actually think about designing your client side logic to deal with scenarios when the session data on the server has expired. To  get/set session data you can use "aspx page methods" or "ajax calls to aspx page methods via jquery" or etc.

Comment: instead now i am using hidden fields. is that fine?

Comment: @AntonyFrancis I can't say. It depends on your requirement. However, its perfectly okay to store in hidden fields. It also depends on the kind of data (specifically its lifetime and nature of use, since you are talking about sessions). I'd say, retrieve such data from server to the client always when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of session variable, set it to a hidden field

```
PageMethods.setpfdetails2(ddlpf.options[ddlpf.selectedIndex].value, userid,onSuc,onErr);
function onSuc(res)
{
   hbm.value=res;
}
```